# LyX Thesis Document Class missing

Tags: lyx

I am writing my Thesis and just noticed that the Thesis Document Class is not available.

On http://wiki.lyx.org/Examples/Thesis#toc1 it says that it is included since v2.0 .

Is there another Document Class I should instead? I was thinking that maybe maybe I could use the Paper class.

Comment: It might be in your examples folder. Can you check there? There should be a folder called "thesis" and inside you should open up thesis.lyx

Comment: @scottkosty You should make that an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the examples folder, open the folder called "thesis" and inside that open thesis.lyx.